# android Application wallpaper set

Tags: android

I m developing an Android chat application where in user will be provided with a set of wallpapers from which he/she can set wallpaper of application window.It is changing wallpaper.How it can be done through code? please help.
I don't want code for system/home screen wallpaper setting.Wanted for chat screen wallpaper changing code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` in your main activity that is showing the chat window.

Comment: Users should be able to change wallpaper of chat screen from set of wallpapers that v provide. How to do it.?

Comment: You can provide a image gallery: use the Gallery object from android,
implement a onClick method for each image and with a button you apply the image to the layout. Have a look into android sdk examples, there is a code example of how to use the gallery :)

Comment: Thanks for Your time..I ll surely see to it... :)